# HTML/CSS only working on the first and last target

Tags: html, css

The following html/css works correctly on the first and last "she loves him a lot." lines, why doesn't it draw the rounded rectangle around the entire sentence for the 3, 4, 5 iterations.

http://jsfiddle.net/xa3apsdc/16/

attention to this code:

```
span[class]:before {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    font:bold 10px arial;
    color:#00f;
    content: attr(class) "";
}
```

Comment: You have given border to only first and last child in CSS.

Comment: You have only given a border to the first and last `span` not sure why you think otherwise. You have used `first-child` & `last-child` to give a border, so thats what you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xa3apsdc/17/)**

CSS:

```
span{
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
      border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:15px;
    padding:2px;
}
```

You have given rounded corner only for first and last child. thats why it was not working

Comment: thank you! d'oh. I was too focused on the bottom part of the code, i didn't see the first/last child part on the span.

Answer (score 2):

that's because you are not using, Add this  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9khc8f70/)

```
span{
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:15px;
padding:2px;
}
```

Comment: you added code same as OP's fiddle demo.. Update the code with your answer :)

Comment: Add your Fiddle into your question, no need to have it as a comment.

Comment: You can edit the answer and add the fiddle instead of a comment!

Comment: thank you, your answer is correct, it looks like K.B.M barely answered before, so it's only fair I accept his answer as answer, but yours is just as good